# How to place objects in ARCore that point in a given geographical direction

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore

I am currently working on an ARCore app and want to place objects (eg. Arrows) in the AR scene that start at the current location of the user and point to geographical north.

My idea was to place objects on the X-axis, rotate them around the Y-axis and at last translate the objects to have their origin in the position of the user. I planned to at first get the device orientation in relation to north (which I am able to do) and also get the orientation in relation to the ARCore world coordinate system. I'm now struggling to do the latter. I think I need the angle around the Y-axis between the X-axis and the current direction of view. I figured out that it should be somehow possible to get this via the Pose:

```
arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame().getCamera().getDisplayOrientedPose();
```

I don’t have any clue what to do with the pose. The values qx(), qy(), qz(), getXAxis(), getYAxis() and getZAxis() don’t seem to be what I expected. As I watched them change while moving the device (after converting them to degrees) they ranged roughly from -55 to 55.

TL;DR: 
 How to rotate objects in ARCore to point to a given geographical direction?

I found this solution but don't know what the 'dHelper' is supposed to be:
[Placing an object with a given compass bearing in ARCore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50894058/placing-an-object-with-a-given-compass-bearing-in-arcore)

Answer (score 0):

to put an arrow on the camera view that will direct you you do not need arcore in any matter. This is siple rotation of na `ImageView`

if you want to rotate 3D object according to the bearing you need to get actual position, target position, count the bearing and rotate based on the int value of degrees that you received from the calculation.

Comment: Maybe I didn't describe my problem well enough: I want to place the object IN the AR scene. For example on the floor or on a table. So that the object stays there an I can move around it.

Comment: @sandroGhost, in that case, I don't see any problem. Just run the samples from ARCore package like HelloSceneform and you have a perfect example of how to do it